# Lost my tokens - need help in figuring out what I did wrong

Tags: hardware-wallets

Can someone give me some advice on a transaction where I seem to have lost some of my tokens.

I’m new to this crypto world and now I’m wondering if I got myself into something I can’t manage.

I had several tokens being held on the exchanges, so I purchased a Ledger wallet and transferred most of them on October 8th from Kucoin to my Ledger wallet.

Two of my tokens could not be withdrawn from Kucoin since Kucoin was hacked and they suspended withdrawals on these two tokens.

They were ZRX and CRPT (ERC20) tokens.

All of the other 3 additional tokens I had on Kucoin were able to be withdrawn.

Two of which were ERC20 tokens, transferred correctly and went into my Ethereum account on Ledger as sub (token) accounts.

One of the transfers was Bitcoin and it went into my Ledger Bitcoin account without any problems.

Finally, on October 23rd the suspension was lifted and withdrawals were then allowed for ZRX and CRPT.

I proceeded to do the transfer and thought everything went okay until I noticed that CRPT didn’t show up in my Ledger wallet but ZRX did.

When I looked on my Kucoin account it showed that both ERC20 token transactions were successful and the tokens were all gone.

The Bitcoin transaction was also successful.

I now have a zero balance in my Kucoin account - which is what wanted.

The transaction details on Kucoin show that the “send to” address for both ERC20 tokens are the same and they match the address presented to me by my Ledger for my Ethereum account on my device.

Since they are both ERC20 tokens they both should have gone into the Ethereum account like all the many other tokens I sent to my Ledger back on October 8th (including transfers from other exchanges).

Both had the correct Ethereum address but ZRX made it but not CRPT.

I’ve waited a couple of days to see if they would show up but they haven’t.

I don’t know if I made a mistake in the transaction but if I did, I can’t figure out what it was.

There’s not a lot of money involved and if I’ve lost them, I can chalk it up to a lesson learned if only I knew what I did wrong.

I now hesitate to make any transactions for fear of a repeat of this episode, especially if it’s a large transaction.

Does anyone have an Idea of what might have happened and whether there’s any way or possibility that I can get my tokens back?

If there is a way, can you help walk me through the process?

Comment: If the transaction went through properly at the correct address, it is very unlikey that you lost your tokens. Ledger wallet does support CRPT, so it should show up in your balance thought. Can you give the tx id of the transfer between kucoin and your ledger ?

Comment: Xavier59 - is this what you are asking for? Transaction Hash: 
  0x5ea02c60ddf4a3dde4c4e42fc8bc8c7dec715ff5eb7efd6bb3b36b56555c6522

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing. Is it safe to post all of the information on the transaction page into this forum? I can copy and paste that information in here if you think it's safe to do that. Please let me know.

Comment: @MickG Enter your address on Etherscan, it will display the amount of ethers and all the tokens you own. If these amounts are correct, it could be a sync problem with ledger. I advise you to directly reach their customer support.

Comment: Thanks clement – I did as you suggested and pasted the “send to” address into Etherscan. Yes, it does show all of the tokens that should be in that account including the CRPT I’m looking for. However, all the other tokens are showing brightly on the left with token amounts and on the right with the current token prices and total dollar amount in the account for that token. The CRPT is showing the correct number of tokens on the left but everything is grayed out and no amounts are showing on the right.  Do you have any idea why this might have happened and how to correct the problem?